3.3V PWM to 0-10V Voltage Converter D A Digital Analog PLC
I am trying to make the 3.3 V PWM to 0-10 V voltage converter D A digital analog PLC circuit.
Kindly suggested me the circuit.

Welcome! What have you tried so far?

What does "3.3 V PWM to 0-10 V voltage converter D A digital analog PLC circuit" mean? What do you want the circuit to do? In what way do you want the circuit to relate to a digital signal? In what way do you want the circuit to relate to a PLC?

You don't give a required output impedance, but to a first order, use your 3v3 pwm signal to driver an optocoupler, with the output connected between a 10V supply and a resistor feeding a grounded capacitor. This will form a level shifter and an RC filter, smoothing the pwm signal into an analog control voltage.
RC values need to be chosen based on load impedance, and pwm frequency.
